# Why does this work? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This works:

```
$('div.hg_logo').hover(
    function(){$(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(31, 197, 78, 0.75)'
    }, 1200)},
    function(){$(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    }, 1200)}
);
```

But given what I know about CSS and about JS it shouldn't!

1 'rgba(31, 197, 78, 0.75)' shouldn't need quotes.
2 backgroundColor should be background-color.
3 Semi-colons should be used after the colors.
4 semi-colons should be used after the interior functions which target 'this'.

The four points above, as I understand it, are proper CSS and JS - yet any of them wrecks this code.

Is it a quirk of $().animate and any chance it will be changed? Or should I just commit to rote memory?

Comment: All your 4 points simply wrong. That's right - every of them

Comment: It seems like you might be confusing CSS syntax and jQuery/javascript syntax.  These are two very different things.  Try giving the documentation for jQuery's animate function a read.  Don't get discouraged!

Comment: 1, 2 & 3: You're setting CSS properties in JavaScript, so you don't write it the same as you would in a CSS file. 4: Semi-colons are optional there - a valid semicolon would be after `1200);` in both cases.

Comment: read the jQuery API docs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No. It is a CSS property, passed as literal string, in order to be interpreted as CSS property by jQuery.
2. No. CSS properties are transformed to [CamelCase when used in JS](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/). Although jQuery can also take them in the hyphenated form, the author of your example has chosen to camel-case them, so they don't need to be quoted. (For reasons of readability.)
3. No. Semicolons in CSS are used to separate multiple rules. The last rule doesn't need to be terminated with a semicolon `#foo { color: white }` is perfectly legal in CSS.
4. No. [Semicolons in JS indicate a logical line ending](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/), nothing else. Also, they are optional, if there's a physical line ending (i.e. a line-break like `\n`) instead.

Comment: Well, for `2` the CSS semantics of `;` are irrelevant anyway. What's being set here is a style property, and those values don't have semicolons in them.

Comment: I think 4 might be talking about the implied semicolons after the `.animate()` call in each anonymous function.

Comment: Also, 2: jQuery [supports hyphen-separated CSS properties](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) in setters and getters, though the camelCase style allows the keys to be left unquoted.

Comment: @cmbuckley Yes, 4 was talking about the implied semicolons after `.animate()`

Ah, good times back in the day when I was first learning.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 'rgba(31, 197, 78, 0.75)' shouldn't need quotes.

Yes it should. It is a STRING of text, not a value. This is because you are working in JS, not in CSS. Anything between the quotes is used as CSS. JS doesn't care what you put in there, it might as well be `'pancake'` (that just wouldn't do anything as CSS obviously).

> 2 backgroundColor should be background-color.

No, `-` means 'minus' in JS. It is already used to do calculations. In CSS it's `background-color`, with jQuery it's `backgroundColor`. There is no reason for it to be exactly the same because this is not a string that is literally inserted as CSS (because it doesn't have quotes around it).

> 3 Semi-colons should be used after the colors.

Semicolons are added by jQuery. There is no need to use something like `'rgba(31, 197, 78, 0.75);'`.

> 4 semi-colons should be used after the interior functions which target 'this'.

It is indeed more consistent to do this, but it isn't needed as there is no line of code in the block containing the function. Usually you don't need a semicolon after the last line of code in a block (blocks are generally encapsulated withing `{` and `}`).

> Is it a quirk of $().animate and any chance it will be changed? Or should I just commit to rote memory?

It's pretty logical and won't be changed anytime soon. I'd recommend learning more about JS and jQuery in general to improve your understanding. Or you can just accept these things and try to remember them ;)